# What is the basic difference between jTextArea.setText() and jTextArea.append() methods?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, netbeans-8

What is the basic difference between `jTextArea.setText()` and `jTextArea.append()` methods from examination point of view?

Comment: What's the basic difference between checking the documentation and asking something on SO that could easily be determined from the documentation? -1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is easily determined by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`setText` replaces the text in the text area. `append` adds a string to the end of the **existing** text.

Comment: okay..so append does the work of concatenation?

Comment: @GarvitSharma yup, exactly.